# C#: Shell/Console framework

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a .NET framework for creating a console application that simulates a shell (like cmd), i.e. with a prompt that takes input for commands (defined by me).

Anyone know of a programming example or framework for doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) already exists.

Comment: Well I'm looking into build a shell of my own with my own commands (in C#), can I do this in PowerShell?

Comment: Certainly: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx

Comment: You can write commands (know as Cmdlets) in either C# or the scripting language itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think Adaptive Console Framework fits your bill perfectly.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29471/Adaptive-Console-Framework-Build-Your-Console-Appl

It is a console application framework that enables you to build your console applications easily and brings flexibility and testability to your console applications built with Microsoft.NET technologies.

With ACF, you may get the following benefits:

```
* Automatic command line argument parsing and validation
* Multiple command line syntax supported
* Generate the command line syntax and argument description automatically
* An command line argument can have many different aliases
* Orderless command line argument parsing (Users do not need to input their arguments in the specific order when using your console application)
* Test Driven Design is supported. ACF makes your console application testable
* ACF brings the flexibility to your console application. You can add or remove the command line syntax just by simple configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small framework for this. You can find it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdxconsole.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

this is the best one, but it's in C++

http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at the Interpreter Design Pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You could look at IronPython. It has an interactive shell and you could read the source code for that.